Remove 0's from a matrix
Hi I have the following data



December
January
February
March
April




0
0
0
0
116282


0
0
116282
116282
0


0
0
0
0
0


0
0
0
0
0


0
0
0
0
0


0
0
0
0
0


0
0
0
0
0


0
0
0
0
0


0
0
0
0
0


0
0
0
0
0


0
0
0
0
0


122207
0
0
0
0


0
122207
122207
0
0



And want the following output



Months
Aging Numbers




December
122207


January
122207


February
116282, 122207


March
116282


April
116282



This data is currently being held in a dynamically generated range and has 2414 rows and 27 columns. Each value represents the cross section of case numbers that receive retro payments in a given month case number 122207 receives a retro payment in december, case number 116282 and 122207 both receive retro payment in February.
I generate the range through the following formula:
=LET(a, RetroTable[Case Number],
     b, RetroTable[Retro Units], 
     c, CHOOSECOLS(RetroTable, XMATCH(Analysis!A2#, RetroTable[#Headers])), 
     a*ABS(b*c))

With A2# being a 27x1 array of months (2 years and 3 months of retro units tracking.
Basically, what happens is if there's a non-0 number in the retro units column of retro table and a non-zero number in the particular month column in the table, then it's considered an aging case, and I want to document it as such. Then multiplying it by the actual number and I get the actual case number.
But what I want is an array that has only the non-zero numbers. I have tried adding in a filter condition, such as:
=LET(a, RetroTable[Case Number],
     b, RetroTable[Retro Units], 
     c, CHOOSECOLS(RetroTable, XMATCH(Analysis!A2#, RetroTable[#Headers])), 
     filter(a*ABS(b*c), a*ABS(b*c)<>0))

But this produces a #VALUE error
I have tried the small formula
=LET(a, RetroTable[Case Number],
     b, RetroTable[Retro Units], 
     c, CHOOSECOLS(RetroTable, XMATCH(Analysis!A2#, RetroTable[#Headers])), 
     SMALL(IF(a*ABS(b*c)=0, "", a*ABS(b*c)), SEQUENCE(ROWS(RetroTable))))

But as the data is needed on a monthly basis, this formula doesn't work because it loses the column/row integrity. It turns everything into a single column, and I need to keep each month separated but connected.
What I want is to remove all the 0s, collapse each monthly column into only its values, and have a variable list length for each month based on how many non zero numbers show up in the original report.

Hey, is the result from XMATCH(Analysis!A2#, RetroTable[#Headers]) a contiguous block?

yes @nkalvi it is a contiguous block

Please post your expected output in the OP by editing the same so that other users can visualize what you need.

Try something along the lines using MAKEARRAY() :


=LET(
     _Body, RetroTable,
     _Rows, MAX(MMULT(SEQUENCE(,ROWS(_Body))^0,N(_Body>0))),
     _Output, IFERROR(MAKEARRAY(_Rows,COLUMNS(_Body),
     LAMBDA(r,c, INDEX(FILTER(INDEX(_Body,,c),INDEX(_Body,,c),""),r))),""),
     VSTACK(RetroTable[#Headers],_Output))


Updated Formula as per expected output edit by OP:


=TRANSPOSE(VSTACK(RetroTable[#Headers],
 BYCOL(RetroTable,LAMBDA(α,TEXTJOIN(",",1,IF(α,α,""))))))



Updated 2024-07-08
=LET(
    comment_1, "Set this to = a*ABS(b*c)",
    case_unit_month, A1:E14,
    header, TAKE(case_unit_month, 1),
    numbers, DROP(case_unit_month, 1),
    aging_case_numbers, BYCOL(
        numbers,
        LAMBDA(col, ARRAYTOTEXT(TOCOL(IF(col, col, NA()), 3)))
    ),
    TRANSPOSE(VSTACK(header, aging_case_numbers))
)



hi @nkalvi - for february, the value should be 116282 and 122207, as both numbers appear.

I'm sorry, forgot to wrap the column :)

let me try something

Ah, yes. Let me plug it in :)

ok so issue - the retro table, is the original data - has 49 columns which have a lot of other information about the cases. What I've shown you is the analysis range that gets information strictly relating to aging case numbers. The formulas that I've put, I've put them into a range and tried to replace the references to tables with the named range, but I keep getting #value errors. The issue shows up in the inner index function as it's trying to reference the named range that I've replaced out.

Also, I have seen #value errors due to CHOOSECOLS. Anyway I'll take another look in a couple of hours or so.

Please take a look at the update when you get a chance. I would like to know whether I have understood the problem :)

yes you understood.
